# Make items in listbox as invisible

Tags: javascript, .net, listbox

I have 2 listboxes(.net) with same list items.
I am binding data to the listboxes at page load itself.
If a user selects an item in one listbox that item should become invisible in the other.
This should happen without actually removing items from them.

Comment: i am able to change the color of the list item in second listbox which is selected in first by using Style(color property).But when i use the same style(visibility:hidden) to make  it invisible its not working

Answer (score 3):

You cannot make `options` in a `select` invisible.  All you can do is remove them (which you say you don't want to do)

You can see this by running this code:

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="4">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2" style="display:none;">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

and noting that the option marked as `display:none;` is still visible.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8dMh/)

Comment: if i remove an item from listbox the data will be lost.Moreover the user may unselect an option then there is a need that particular option should be attached to listbox again at its previous position

Comment: @RajReddy - then you'll have to remove the option and save it, then add it back to the listbox later

Comment: @RajReddy—you can store the removed options in an object, select element with `display:none` or a [document fragment](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-B63ED1A3) so they are still available later.

Comment: can anyone provide a simple example?

Comment: @RajReddy - I was bored at work - is this what you want?  http://jsfiddle.net/Y4cZV/2/ :)